# Encontrar un número divisible entre otro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Acabo de conseguirlo pero ahora me surge otro problema:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#convert-btn").click(function(){
  var value = $('#value').val();

  var numerator = parseInt(value);
  var denominator = 180;
  for (var x = 2; ((numerator % x == 0) && (denominator % x == 0)) && x <= 10; x++) {
      console.log(x);
      numerator /= x;
      denominator /= x;
      console.log("Numerator: " + numerator);
      console.log("Denominator: " + denominator);
  }

  var result = "<span class='frac'><sup>"+ numerator + "π" + "</sup><span>/</span><sub>" + denominator + "</sub></span>";
    $("#result").append(result);
});
});
```

Creo que hay un error en el bucle for porque por ejemplo si meto 120 la consola me responde esto:

```
2
Numerator: 60
Denominator: 90
3
Numerator: 20
Denominator: 30
```

Ahora llega hasta el 3 pero no parecer seguir subiendo porque el 5 no me lo detecta por ejemplo.

Comment: ¿Porqué el 180?

Comment: Porque estoy intentando hacer un convertidor de grados a radianes, y necesito el 180 para hacer la regla de tres, estoy intentando hacer que la fracción de los radianes se simplifique.

Comment: Creo que allí esta el detalle, puedes imprimir también el valor de `(numerator % x)` y  de `(180 % x)`, para que valides cuando en verdad se esta convirtiendo en `true` tu condición.  Considero que tendrías que hacerlo por separado, primero un `for` para encontrar el primer numero divisible y después continuas con la validación de los radianes.

Comment: Yo veo que mientras uses el operador `&&` siempre retornará el primer valor y el segundo no será tomado en cuenta, quizás pueda ser parte del error, debes cambiarlo al operador `||` @Raúl

Comment: @Raúl ¿Cuál? Puedes actualizar la pregunta de ser necesario

Comment: **NO** edites tu pregunta cada vez que tengas una nueva duda... haz una nueva pregunta... porque si no no tienen sentidos las respuestas ya dadas

Answer (score 1):

Tu error debe estar en el `for` en esta parte `((numerator % x)&&(180 % x))==0` sera mejor que lo reemplaces por `((numerator % x)==0&&(180 % x)==0)`

te pongo un funcionamiento de ejemplo:

```js
var numerator = 25;
for (var x = 2; x < 10; x++){
  var test1 = ((numerator % x)&&(180 % x))==0
  var test2 = ((numerator % x))
  var test3 = ((180 % x))
  var test4 = ((numerator % x)==0&&(180 % x)==0)
  console.log('Dice que 25 % '+x+' && 180 % '+x+' es igual al 0 --> '+test1)
  console.log('Dice que 25 % '+x+' es igual a --> '+test2)
  console.log('Dice que 180 % '+x+' es igual a --> '+test3)
  console.log('Entonces 25 % '+x+' == 0 && 180 % '+x+' == 0 --> '+test4)
  console.log(' ')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ahora mostrando todos los resultados con los que se puede dividir:

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#result").html('');
  var numerator = $('input').val();
  var denominator = 180;
  
  for (var x = 1; x < 10; x++){
    
    var test4 = ((numerator % x) == 0 && (180 % x) == 0)
    
    console.log('Entonces ' + numerator + ' % ' + x + ' == 0 && ' + denominator + ' % ' + x + ' == 0 --> ' + test4)
    
    if(test4){
      
      numerator /= x;
      denominator /= x;
      
      var result = "<span class='frac'><sup>"+ numerator + "π" + "</sup><span>/</span><sub>" + denominator + "</sub></span>";
      
      $("#result").append(result); 
      
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='value'>
<button id='convert-btn'>Convertir</button>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: Tienes razón ahora ya sólo me sale hasta el numerador= 30 y denominador = 45, pero debería seguir el bucle encontrar el 5 y dividirlo entre 5 pero no lo hace,la página se queda indefinidamente pensando debido a que algún loop no debe terminar. @JuankGlezz

Comment: lo que tu quieres es encontrar todos los que sean divisibles y mostrarlos?

Comment: Sí, más que mostrarlos dividir el numerador y el denominador por ellos, pero sí

Comment: @Raúl he modificado la respuesta, espero que sea lo que busques

Comment: Lo he probado y no imprime nada, ni siquiera la consola. Mira mi pregunta, también la editado, ahora ya me divide por más números que el 2, pero por ejemplo no lo divide por 5 y no entiendo el por qué. @JuankGlezz

Comment: @Raúl haz cambiado los `id`? no entiendo porque poner `((numerator % x == 0) && (denominator % x == 0))` dentro de la validación del `for` si se encuentra con un `false` ya no continuara ejecutándose, he modificado a como lo tienes en tu pregunta la ultima edición

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he conseguido todo el proceso, aquí os lo dejo por si os sirve de algo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#convert-btn").click(function(){
  var value = $('#value').val();

  var numerator = parseInt(value);
  var denominator = 180;
  for (var x = 2; x <= 10; x++) {
      if((numerator % x == 0) && (denominator % x == 0)){
        numerator /= x;
        denominator /= x;
        console.log("Numerator: " + numerator);
        console.log("Denominator: " + denominator);
        if((numerator % x == 0) && (denominator % x == 0)){
          numerator /= x;
          denominator /= x;
          console.log("Numerator: " + numerator);
          console.log("Denominator: " + denominator);
        }
      }
  }

  var result = "<span class='frac'><sup>"+ numerator + "π" + "</sup><span>/</span><sub>" + denominator + "</sub></span>";
    $("#result").append(result);
});
});
```